# How To Read OPDS Catalog (ex : http://feedbooks.com/catalog.atom)

Tags: php

I'm new in PHP. I want to read OPDS catalog (ex : http://feedbooks.com/catalog.atom) and then store the catalogs into json file.

Could someone suggest me how to do it, or point me to usefull article/source code to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Open the URL (allow_url_fopen must be switched on for that, otherwise take a look at `curl`)

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://feedbooks.com/catalog.atom');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
print_r($xml);
```

the print_r will show you the object you received, alter the object as you like and create a JSON via json_encode($xml), and write it to a file.

Alternatively you can use a Yahoo Pipe to read the feed and output it as json.

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=29ec5982a8bede87d83a402f7f8ac0ec&_render=json');
```

That's the actual pipe: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=29ec5982a8bede87d83a402f7f8ac0ec&_render=json